# Prevent Object Download, Saving, Zooming, etc

Tags: php, javascript, html, object

I am display a pdf online inside an object. When a person clicks on it, they have the option to download, zoom in, etc. I was wondering is there an option or way to prevent this(parameters, javascript)?

Current object code is this:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
    width="99%" height="99%" id="pdf" >
    <param name="movie" value="filename.pdf">
    <param name="quality" value="high">
    <param name="bgcolor" value="##FFFFFF">
    <embed src="filename.pdf" quality="high" bgcolor="##FFFFFF" width="99%" height="99%"
            name="2003map" align="" type="pdf">
    </embed>
</object>
```

Comment: anyway it can be downloaded, there is no way to ultimately prevent it and keep ability to let users 
view it.

Answer (score 2):

Put invisible mask on top of the OBJECT tag :) Just make sure you don't make scrollbar inaccessible as well. Another drawback is, user will lose ability of right-click-context menu specific to the application [e.g. Adobe Reader].

Comment: What do you mean by an invisible mask?

Comment: An empty layer, on top of OBJECT, same width and height and position. Everything below it will be un-clickable = inaccessible. Frustrating experience for user, let me tell you.

Comment: If your users know anything about web dev, than it is easy to get around. Break out firebug, set display none on the element and get the content. There is no way to prevent the user from getting it if they really want it.

Comment: I am trying to Z-Index the element by the object always appear over the div. Any other solutions for masking it?

Comment: Try adding `<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />` to OBJECT. It works for Flash, may fail here.

Comment: @epascarello : What is the probability of that? You can't stop everyone, but definitely can decrease the amount of damage done.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is just plain wrong. Atleast add that you're only making it more difficult but not impossible. Also, by make it more difficult, you make your website harder to use. Can you afford that tradeoff? If someone can see the PDF, he can print it and rescan it.... always!

Comment: @Konerak: UNLESS that Pdf is print- and save-protected. WHICH can be cracked using correct tools :)

Comment: Yes, its for a client, its what he wants, I just find the solution, like many of you I suppose. Yes I know it won't be perfect by its meant to stop the average user. Nothing is perfect, including facebook attempt to prevent downloading of images, just turn off javascript, lol. The param options are not working. I think I'm going to go with a flash player.

Comment: But good to know that an object will ovveride css elements to always appear on top, including if its implemented in an Iframe.

Comment: Excluding the WMODE=opaque for Flash Objects.